# C++ on Qt creator: debugger not showing static array elements

Tags: debug, c++, qt

I'm using Qt creator and I swear I've seen it display static array elements before. I don't recall updating the IDE, the compiler, the debugger or anything else, so I'm not sure what's going on. I've tried the two ways I know to display array elements and none of them seem to be working.

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Student
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string email;
    long int phone;
};
```

and then a static array like this:

```
Student students[100];
```

which I'm populating with test data in this function:

```
void populateStudents(Student students[], int &size)
{
    students[0]={14562, "Bill Stewart", "bstewart@example.com", 56723565};
    students[1]={12684, "Joan Murray", "jmurray@example.com", 43560056};
    students[2]={13118, "Alex Taylor", "ataylor@example.com", 64223053};
    students[3]={11902, "Pamela Brandon", "pbrandon@example.com", 74534230};
    size=4;
}
```

So I also have this function to find a specific item in the array:

```
string findName(Student students[], int size, int id){
    for (int i=0; i!=size; i++){
        if (students[i].id==id)
            return students[i].name;
    }
    return "";
}
```

and I'm exploring the data while it's being executed, but I've tried adding "@10" to the expression evaluator to show the first 10 items in the array, but I only get the first one displayed and some of the items show up as pointers...
[image: first method]

Also tried adding a new expression evaluator like this: **Student[10]students** (c*lass name[items I want to view]variable name*) but this time it doesn't even recognize my array:
[image: second method]

Of course, the data is correctly stored in the array and the program is working fine, only the debugger is not showing the data correctly.

I recall using both methods in the past and seeing them work... What am I missing here?
These are my debugging settings:
[image: settings 1]
[image: settings 2]

Comment: Arrays are pointers to a memory address in C++.  So each Student entry in the array is a pointer to a Student object in a array.  The first entry is a pointer to address at the beginning of the array

Comment: You are not passing the beginning address of the array to your function.  So a new array is being created and then orphaned in memory.  You never actually fill the original array you created.  **Your problem is your code.**.  Which means this is more of a SO question since you have a logical error in your code

Comment: You can see this is true by the fact the memory address spaces are completely different between the two arrays.  Yes, your code works, but it has logical error and likely a memory leak associated with that error

Comment: Should add I determined this based on the small snippets you provided and it only appears to be what I describe (based on my own experience dealing with C++ structure arrays

Comment: Hmm I'm confused now... I always thought static arrays were automatically passed by reference when being used as parameters, as a pointer to the first array item. Even so, it's weird that some items are displayed as being of the "Student" type while other are displayed as pointers to Student items...

Comment: Which should be a clue you need to dereference those pointers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454990/why-cant-we-pass-arrays-to-function-by-value